# Better alternative to Circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm a bit confused about all possible package to draw electrical circuits. I'm new to drawing these diagrams (although I'm well known to TikZ).

Is there a better package than circuitikz? I found it's documentation a bit confusing. But above all, it doesn't seem to be aiming it the **ultimate consistency** I'm looking for (oh god, how I love consistency). Even the code isn't consistent (to my TikZ-used eyes at least).

Is someone using another package that does the trick (perhaps a TikZ library I don't know of)? I'd like to keep on using TikZ though, so don't stray too far.

PS: this is not a *diss* for the Circuitikz package. It's been the best packege I found to draw circuitz so far and seems to do quite well. It just hasn't got the ulimate tweaking abilities I want. (If it does, please enlighten me!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about [pst-circ](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-circ/). It modifies the way you can compile your latex document.

Comment: please refer to the current version: http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-circ/

Answer (score 8):

`TikZ`, starting version 2.10 has its own circuits library, which works very well (for me :) ).